# Material UI + styled with props throws "React does not recognize zIndex prop on a DOM element."

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm struggling with React error -> `React does not recognize zIndex prop on a DOM element.`
It happens when I'm using MUI component and Styled with props.

Code example:

styled:

```
import {Drawer as DrawerBase, styled} from '@material-ui/core'

interface DrawerProps {
  zIndex: number
}
export const Drawer = styled(DrawerBase)<Theme, DrawerProps>(({zIndex}) => ({
  zIndex
}))
```

implementation:

```
<Drawer zIndex={10} />
```

I'm using:
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3"

Is there any possibility to prevent passing props to DOM elements?

Comment: Try transient props from styled components

Comment: Usless comment, I clearly told which version of material-ui I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Material UI's 'styled' syntax is very confusing unfortunately. This should work though:

```
interface DrawerProps {
  zIndex: number
}

export const Drawer = styled(DrawerBase, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'zIndex',
})<Theme, DrawerProps>(({zIndex}) => ({
  zIndex
}))
```

'shouldForwardProp' is also an unfortunate name as it sounds like the property zIndex isn't forwarded, but it is actually accessible.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used styled components within MUI before, so take what I'm saying with a grain of salt. But I have a few ideas:

You're importing `styled` from `'@material-ui/core'`, but you're calling a `style` function (without the "d").

Looking at the [MUI docs for using styled components](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#styled-components), they're using it the way we traditionally use styled components, which is using CSS syntax. I'd expect your code to look like this:

```js
const Drawer = styled(DrawerBase)`
  z-index: ${props => props.zIndex};
`;
```

The DOM element needs "z-index", not "zIndex".

Your code snippet also has a typo with your `const Drawer` where you've left out the "s": `cont`.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Let's skip all of the typos in here. I just wrote it by myself here to not copy the source code from the project, but the example is 1:1 reproduction. Also, typescript doesn't allow me to use it as you've presented here

Comment: Gotcha. I figured the typos were just for the sample code. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.